# Set ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables when Verb="runas"

Tags: c#, environment-variables, processstartinfo, runas

I am developing a C# application.

I need to create and pass variables to a new process and I am doing it using `ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables`.

The new process must run elevated so I am using Verb = "runas"

```
var startInfo =  new ProcessStartInfo(command)
{
    UseShellExecute = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Verb = "runas"
};
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in enviromentVariables)
{
    startInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add(entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value.ToString());
}
```

The problem is that according to the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables.aspx):

> You must set the **`UseShellExecute` property to false** to start the process after changing the `EnvironmentVariables` property. If `UseShellExecute` is true, an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown when the Start method is called.

but the `runas` variable requires **UseShellExecute=true**

Is there a way to do both: run process as elevated and also set the environment variables?

**EDIT**

I will try to rephrase my question...

Is there a way to pass arguments securly to another process so only the other process will be able to read the arguments.

Comment: Maybe not nice but might work: create a batchfile first and set the environment vars with setx /M key value. You first run the batch script and then real command. That will clutter your machinewide environmentvars though.

Comment: Thanks, but that might cause a security hole, because everyone running under this user can read the global enviorment variables

Comment: Yeah, I already said that it wasn't nice...and that was an understatement :-(

Comment: Did you try setting the Environment vars in (by means of System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(key, balue)); and then start the process?

Comment: but how can I do that when UseShellExecute = true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works but on the downside is that it also shows a second command prompt, the enviroment vars are only set in the context of the started process so the settings are not propagating to the whole box.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var command = "cmd.exe";
        var environmentVariables = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
        environmentVariables.Add("some", "value");
        environmentVariables.Add("someother", "value");

        var filename = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".cmd";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename);
        sw.WriteLine("@echo off");
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in environmentVariables)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("set {0}={1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
        } 
        sw.WriteLine("start /w {0}", command);
        sw.Close();
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(filename) {
            UseShellExecute = true, 
            Verb="runas"
        };
        var ps =  Process.Start(psi);
        ps.WaitForExit();
        File.Delete(filename);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! do you know how secure this approach is?

Comment: Very secure or very unsecure, depends on your context. Are you planning to do very unsecure things?

Comment: I am passing a password to my application. I need that no one except the new process will be able to read the password. I am also checking if the exe is signed before calling it.

Comment: Then don't use a temporary batch file, since it will be readable for the duration of the program. You could use a custom wrapper program that receives the password via a shared memory block. (And overwrites it as soon as it is received.)

Comment: And where do you plan storing the password?

Comment: I plan to encrypt it with a password that I will ask from the user to enter.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better answer: you can still call Process.Start() with a ProcessStartInfo that has UseShellExecute = true, provided that the method you call it from has been labeled with the [STAThread] attribute.