# CMD Command doesn't execute

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, runas, start-process

I'm trying to run this command in cmd from c# but for some reason it doesn't work. But when I change my Argument to "/C ipconfig" it work perfectly. I don't understand why. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
   Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/C wbadmin start backup - backupTarget:{TargetBackupDrive}: -include:{LocationOs}: -allcritical - quiet";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        process.Start();
        CmdOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: [The docs for wbadmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wbadmin) say that it must run elevated. Is your app running as an admin?

Comment: Why do you `RedirectStandardInput = true` then never provide any input?

Comment: Yeah, my bad I forgot to remove it. But it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @CodeStranger I'm writing in it visuals studio (which I run it as admin) and I added a Verb = "runas" so it will launch as an admin.

Comment: @OlivierRogier I checked those posts before I post my question. It didn't work.

Comment: The code you posted cannot work. You are trying to use `runas`, while at the same time set `UseShellExecute` to `false`. Since `wbadmin` requires an elevated process to work, the code you posted cannot work.

Comment: Does code run outside VS?  VS does not use Admin unless you right click the VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Even when I set it to true, it doen't execute at all.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, VS is running as admin.

Answer (score 0):

The verb "runas" does not work when UseShellExecute is set to false as it is pointed out here: [Set ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables when Verb="runas"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827486/set-processstartinfo-environmentvariables-when-verb-runas)

You could either provide admin credentials with the UserName and Password properties our set UseShellExecute to true and execute your command in the shell.

Comment: I tried to set the UseShellExecute to true. But It didn't change anything.